# Howto simply setup an J2EE Project with JSF capability in IntelliJ

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, setup-project

I have setup a new Project by selecting J2EE and JSF and let IntelliJ create the project.
IntelliJ also create a Glassfish server for me.
I didn't change any code so far.

When starting the server I get the following Error:
Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

Glassfish's log output is:

```
  Critical error during deployment: 
javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:242)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:499)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1404)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:526)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5043)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:592)
```

Whats wrong here, or how can I simply setup such a project ?

Comment: Did you bundle the JSF libraries within your application or not? And please post version info of Glassfish and JSF

Comment: And 'errors' make great search engine keywords: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=javax.faces.FacesException%3A+Unable+to+find+CDI+BeanManager